# AWS offerings for monitoring EC2 Tomcat Web Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a java web application running on Tomcat deployed on an EC2 instance. Is there any way I can monitor/set alarms for when the web application goes down or stops responding? Essentially what I would like to do is to check if a HTTP request to the web app responds with status 200. If it does not respond with 200 (for a few times) then it should raise an alarm and send an e-mail to some ops people.

I know there are third party options like Nagois / uptimerobot that I could use but I wanted to know if there are any AWS offerings for this? Is it possible to set up such automated monitoring using AWS Cloud Watch? I could not find a way to do this based on what I read up about Cloud Watch. If this isn't the sort of thing Cloud Watch can handle, then is there another AWS service suited for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think Port Monitoring Feature is available under AWS Beanstalk.

You can consider checking this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html

Answer (score 0):

Ashutosh,

Ec2 is an IAAS service from AWS and you will not have an AWS offering to monitor your Tomcat server. However, you have custom-built solutions, which I think you are not looking for here.

However, if you are using an Application Load balancer or Beanstalk you get options to trigger alarms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can achieve it through a cloudwatch . collect your logs with a cloudwatch agent and upload it on  cloudwatch logstream.  below is the reference url for configuring cloudwatch agent.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html

After that with "create matrix filter" you can set up an email trigger as per your requirements.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringPolicyE
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Counting404Responses.htmlxamples.html